# Raster Projection Error 999999

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcmap, wgs84, error-999999

I tried to change the coordinate system of a TIFF file from UTM to Albers Equal Conic using project raster tool. However, I keep getting this error. Any one knows why? where is the problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: What were the parameter values that you supplied to the Project Raster tool?

Comment: Try not using the background geoprocessor and use ArcCatalog to perform the projection. Do you have enough space on your system drive to hold the temporary raster? If not you might want to set your environment TEMP and TMP variables to a disc that has more free space https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/121855-edit-user-system-environment-variables-windows.html#option1

Comment: Your log shows a number of Define Projection commands, which shouldn't be necessary if the original projections are known.